# integrate xsolla webhooks using php sdk

Tags: php, ip, webhooks, local, playfab

im using xsolla webhooks with php sdk and i can't run my code with webhooks localy

i get this error :

```
"error": {
        "code": "INVALID_CLIENT_IP",
        "message": "Client IP address (127.0.0.1) not found in allowed IP addresses whitelist (159.255.220.240\/28, 185.30.20.16\/29, 185.30.21.0\/24, 185.30.21.16\/29). Please check troubleshooting section in README.md https:\/\/github.com\/xsolla\/xsolla-sdk-php#troubleshooting"
    }
```

im using xsolla webhooks with php sdk and i can't run my code with webhooks localy

i get this error :

```
"error": {
        "code": "INVALID_CLIENT_IP",
        "message": "Client IP address (127.0.0.1) not found in allowed IP addresses whitelist (159.255.220.240\/28, 185.30.20.16\/29, 185.30.21.0\/24, 185.30.21.16\/29). Please check troubleshooting section in README.md https:\/\/github.com\/xsolla\/xsolla-sdk-php#troubleshooting"
    }
```

and when i added ip adress 127.0.01

like that :

```
protected static $xsollaSubnets = [
        '159.255.220.240/28',
        '185.30.20.16/29',
        '185.30.21.0/24',
        '127.0.0.1',
        '185.30.21.16/29',
    ];
```

it show me another error :

```
  "error": {
            "code": "INVALID_SIGNATURE",
            "message": "\"Authorization\" header not found in Xsolla webhook request. Please check troubleshooting section in README.md https:\/\/github.com\/xsolla\/xsolla-sdk-php#troubleshooting"
        }
```

any one can help with that ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

"INVALID_SIGNATURE" error code with message "Authorization header not found in Xsolla webhook request"

php-cgi under Apache does not pass HTTP Basic user/pass to PHP by default.

In order to get this working you need to add the following line to .htaccess or httpd.conf Apache file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```